# How can I implement JS so that when I hover an image in a gallery it affects every other image except the hovered image?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating an image thumbnail gallery where each thumbnail will be a link to a full size image on another page. So far when a user hovers over an image a red box covers the image using a CSS ::before pseudo class.

```css
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.overlay>img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.overlay::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/280x280"></div>
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/333x111"></div>
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/111x333"></div>
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/222x222"></div>
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/111x172"></div>
```

I would like to change the interaction so that when a user hovers on an image, every other image in the gallery (with an 'overlay' class) will be covered by the red box, except for the image being hovered over. This would create a focus on the image being hovered over by covering the other images with red.

It seems Javascript would be the best way to make this work, how can I implement js with what I've already written?

I was also trying out CSS [:not pseudo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) but having trouble making it work.

Comment: You could use ~ to get the effect to happen on overlay elements after the hovered one. But there is no way using pure CSS to select the ones before

Comment: Have you written any Javascript that you could show us. For example on a mouse over event.

Comment: If you want to create focus without javascript, use backdrop (f.e. with blur).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.overlay').hover(fnOver, fnOut)
  function fnOver() {
      $('.overlay').not(this).addClass('active')
  }
  function fnOut() {
      $('.overlay').not(this).removeClass('active')
  }
```

```css
 .overlay {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.overlay>img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.overlay::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}

.active::before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="overlay"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/280x280"></div>
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/333x111"></div>
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/111x333"></div>
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/222x222"></div>
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/111x172"></div>
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! I haven't heard of traversing in jquery before. The ease transition no longer works, but that is not a deal breaker for me.

Comment: I updated my answer, the ease transition is working. You can try it again.